# How to disable VS Code integrated terminal Intellisense via `Set-PSReadLineOption -PredictionSource None`

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code

A day or two ago, the integrated terminal in VS Code started using `Powershell Predictive Intellisense`, I think this post might be related to it? (https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/18542)

Regardless, it seems like all you have to do is issue the `Set-PSReadLineOption -Prediction Source None` command to turn it off. My issue is, I think?, ..is that I do not know how to create a `$profile` for the VS Code terminal in order to get this disabled. At the moment, I am having to issue the `Set-PSReadLineOption -Prediction Source None` command for each new terminal I bring up in VS Code which is super annoying. This is only happening with the VS Code powershell terminal at the moment. Outside of VS Code it isn't happening *yet*.

Anyone having this issue? And how did you solve it? I am am totally clueless when it comes to PowerShell `$profiles` so all I would do is cause more issues if I started a "trail and error" approach. :D

**What I've tried**: I noticed I had a `$profile` file in my Documents so I put the command in there but no change. I've since taken that out so it wouldn't possibly causes issues elsewhere.

Comment: VSCode has always provided intellisense. - You make setups in VSCode user settings. All you need is in the VSCode documentation, from creating a profile to configuring user settings.

Comment: Don’t guess about different PowerShell versions. Check it, then update your question with this information.

Answer (score 2):

As per my comment. See the docs.

> Setting up Visual Studio Code
>
> https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/setup/setup-overview
>
> Terminal Profiles in Visual Studio Code
>
> https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/terminal/profiles
>
> User and Workspace Settings
>
> https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings
>
> PowerShell in Visual Studio Code
>
> https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/powershell

Creating a PowerShell/pwsh profile is the same as you would in PS/pwsh normally. In VSC PowerShell shells, just this:

```
New-Item –Path $Profile –Type File –Force
```

Each profile for PowerShell and VSC are in these locations:

```
# PSCore
C:\Users\...\Documents\PowerShell
Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1

# WinPS and VSCode
C:\Users\...\Documents\WindowsPowerShell
Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1
Microsoft.PowerShellISE_profile.ps1
Microsoft.VSCode_profile.ps1
```

You make PSReadsline settings in those as normal so that you have what you need depending on the shell/console you are in.

Lastly, this command is not valid:

```
Set-PSReadLineOption -Prediction Source None
```

It should be:

```
Set-PSReadLineOption -PredictionSource None
```

Though that may just be a typo on your post.
Just put that line in each of the above profiles if they are there.

For Example, in my PS profiles, to prevent IntelliSense, I have this:

```
If ($Host.Name -notmatch 'ISE')
{ 
    Import-Module -Name PSReadline 
    Set-PSReadLineOption -HistoryNoDuplicates -ShowToolTips
    # Set-PSReadLineOption -PredictionSource History
    Set-PSReadLineOption -PredictionSource None
    #Import-Module Microsoft.PowerShell.Management -UseWindowsPowerShell -NoClobber
}
```

In my VSCode profile, I have this:

```
Set-PSReadLineOption -HistoryNoDuplicates -ShowToolTips
Set-PSReadLineOption -PredictionSource None
```

Or the edit directly. Using the Cog in the bottom left corner.

[image]

Comment: OP isn’t talking about the editor but the terminal.

Comment: @DanielB, I get that but included to rest for the OP's clarification for location information to consider where changes may be needed for whatever use case is needed. Hence the pointers to the ```*profile*``` pointers, and VSC docs reference pointer to the ```Terminal``` config details.